# How to configure factories with complicated dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can get this test to work with a poor rspec design.  I'm trying to move my dependencies in to factories but it's not working.  I can't figure out a way to both have `data_service` available to call in a test, and to have it automatically created with the `data_service_owner` factory.

Here's the spec file:

```
describe Foo do

  shared_context "notify" do
    let!(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }
    let!(:foo) { FactoryGirl.create(:foo) }
    let!(:message) { FactoryGirl.create(:message) }
    let!(:bar) { FactoryGirl.create(:bar) }
  end

  describe "#notify(subscriber)" do
  include_context "notify"

    it "notifies bars" do
      bar.foo = foo #shouldn't have to do this
      bar.save #shouldn't have to do this
      expect { foo.notify_on_subscribe(subscriber) }.to change { Notification.all.count }.by(1)
    end
end
```

I've tested all of the individual factories successfully.  Here the `data_service_owner` factory:

```
factory :bar do
    boolean_attr true
    employee
    foo #if I put FactoryGirl.create(:foo) here, it is not associated with the same foo object I defined in the let! statement
  end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to associate it in your let block by doing something like

```
let!(:bar) { FactoryGirl.create(:bar, foo: foo) }
```

and that should associate it with the foo that you'd created above